# accessing context object in onViewCreated() method of fragment class - null context case

Tags: android, fragment

I need to use context in onViewCreated() method of Fragment. In some cases context may be null in production. In my tests, i do not come across this case. I read similar questions and infer the below solution however i am not sure it is a good practice or not and as i said earlier i do not come across the failure case in test. Any suggesitons will be appreciated.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_something, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        if(this.context==null)
            return;

        // i need to use fragment here.
    }
}
```

Comment: In your onAttach() method use this.context = getActivity();   Update this and try.

Comment: ok i edited my question.

Comment: now you can run and test... it's work or not ?

Comment: as i a said earlier, there is no problem in my test cases. my quesiton is different.  i ask whether this is a good practice or not. i wrote the above code in notepad for asking question. you didnt understand my question

Answer (score 1):

For checking null context checking in `onViewCreated` you can create a context on a Fragment class is a good practice. Somehow context can be null in `onViewCreated` method.

You can get the context in fragment in any position by using `getContext()`. For better, you can set context value in `onCreateView` and then check the context in `onCreatedView()` method.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.context = getContext()
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_something, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        if(context == null)
            return;

        // i need to use fragment here.
    }
}
```

And if you need Activity then the better to get the activity in `onActivityCreated` by using `getActivity()`.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Hope you understand.